# If $(X_n, d_n)$ is a family of complete metric spaces, prove that $(X,d)$ is complete

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X_n, d_n)$ be a family of complete metric spaces. Prove that $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space.

$$
X = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n = \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : x_j \in X_j \}
$$

Furthermore let $(\gamma_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset (0, \infty)$ be a seq. s.t $\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} \gamma_n < \infty$. For $x,y \in X$ where $x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $y = (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ define

$$
d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n \frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,y_n)}
$$

Where $d_n$ is the metric on $X_n$

This is what I have come up with.

Let $(x^m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be Cauchy seq in $X$. Thus we know that $(x_n^m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cachy in $X_n$ (I proved that earlies problem). Hence $(x_n^m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to some $x_n \in X_n$. Then

$$
d(x_n^m, x_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n \frac{d_n(x_n^m, x_n)}{1 + d_n(x_n^m,x_n)} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon} = \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n < \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon} \cdot M < \epsilon \cdot M
$$

Where $M = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n$ since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n < \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step $$\tag{*}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n \frac{d_n\left(x_n^m, x_n\right)}{1 + d_n\left(x_n^m, x_n\right)} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon}$$ 
need to be more detailed; in particular, we have to precise for which $m$'s it holds. It seems that you use the fact that $d_n\left(x_n^m, x_n\right) \lt\varepsilon$ for $m$ large enough, but the "large enough" may depend on the considered $m$. Nevertheless, an inequality similar to (*) does hold for $m$ large enough. Indeed, fix a positive $\epsilon$. There exists $M$ such that if $m,m'\geqslant M$, then $d\left(x^m,x^{m'}  \right) \lt\epsilon$. We thus have for any fixed $N$ and $m,m'\geqslant M$ that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \gamma_n \frac{d_n\left(x_n^m, x_n^{m'}  \right)}{1 + d_n\left(x_n^m, x_n\right)} \lt \epsilon.$$
In particular, letting $m'$ going to infinity, we get for any $N\geqslant 1$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \gamma_n \frac{d_n\left(x_n^m, x_n\right)}{1 + d_n\left(x_n^m, x_n\right)} \leqslant \epsilon .$$
 This implies by letting $N$ going to $+\infty$ that $d\left(x^{(m)},x\right)\leqslant \varepsilon$ for each $m\geqslant M$.

Comment: Since $X_n$ is complete, I know that every Cauchy seq. converge. Thus if $x_n$ is the limit of the Cauchy seq $(x_n^m)$ then I know that there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall m > n_0 \Rightarrow d_n(x_n^m,x_n) < \epsilon$. That is how I resonead. Not just "large enough".

Comment: But this $n_0$ may be dependent on $n$.

Comment: Let $p_1, p_2, \dots \in \mathbb{N}$ be those numbers such that if $m_i>p_i$ then $d_i1(x_1^{m_1},x_1), d_2(x_2^{m_{2}}, x_2) \dots < \epsilon$, then let $m = \text{max}\{m_i\}$?

Comment: Sorry I missed in "if $m, m' \geq M$, then $d(x^m,x^{m'}) < \epsilon$" that it was $d$ and not $d_n$!

Comment: Why must we fix $N$? Are we not able to let $m' \to \infty$ otherwise?

Comment: It is in general not trivial to take a limit into an infinite sum, but we can do this into a finite sum.